# compact binary representation of json

Tags: json, binary, format

Are there any compact binary representations of JSON out there?  I know there is [BSON](http://bsonspec.org), but even that webpage says "in many cases is not much more efficient than JSON. In some cases BSON uses even more space than JSON".

I'm looking for a format that's as compact as possible, preferably some kind of open standard?

Comment: why can't you use compression at server?

Comment: BSON specs are far from optimal in both size and efficiency. Maybe you should consider storing compressed JSON (with deflate or something).

Comment: @Andrey that may be a possible solution, but i'm looking to see if there is a way to reduce the amount of data we feed to the underlying stream (which already has an option to do compression on the fly).  in theory, it should be easier to compress it at the object encoding level since we have context about the tags etc

Comment: Regardless of whether more compact binary format is used, for compression LZF is pretty nice, as it is much faster to compress than gzip (deflate), with slightly lower compression ratio.

Comment: MessagePack reduces the json original verbosity. http://msgpack.org

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes: [Smile](https://github.com/FasterXML/smile-format-specification) data format (see [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smile_(data_interchange_format)). It has public Java implementation, C version in the works at github (libsmile). It has benefit of being more compact than JSON (reliably), but being 100% compatible logical data model, so it is easy and possible to convert back and forth with textual JSON.

For performance, you can see [jvm-serializers](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/) benchmark, where smile competes well with other binary formats (thrift, avro, protobuf); sizewise it is not the most compact (since it does retain field names), but does much better with data streams where names are repeated.

It is being used by projects like Elastic Search and Solr (optionally), Protostuff-rpc supports it, although it is not as widely as say Thrift or protobuf.

EDIT (Dec 2011) -- there are now also `libsmile` bindings for PHP, Ruby and Python, so language support is improving. In addition there are measurements on data size; and although for single-record data alternatives (Avro, protobuf) are more compact, for data streams Smile is often more compact due to key and String value back reference option.

Comment: Smile: strange specs despite the project goals.

Comment: @StaxMan can you please provide link to Protostuff-rpc project?

Comment: @StaxMan I didn't find any ready-to-use RPC implementation there. Did you? protostuff provides ability to write custom code generators to build your own RPC on top. But it seems to be all.

Comment: hmmh. I must admit I haven't used it, just browsed web page. But I know its author is very helpful, so maybe contact him (David) directly? Btw, love your nickname (once wrote a java app named Fractalizer) :)

Comment: Link-rot has eaten the first link.

Answer (score 17):

You could take a look at the [Universal Binary JSON specification](http://ubjson.org/). It won't be as compact as Smile because it doesn't do name references, but it is 100% compatible with JSON (where as BSON and BJSON define data structures that don't exist in JSON so there is no standard conversion to/from).

It is also (intentionally) criminally simple to read and write with a standard format of:

```
[type, 1-byte char]([length, 4-byte int32])([data])
```

So simple data types begin with an ASCII marker code like 'I' for a 32-bit int, 'T' for true, 'Z' for null, 'S' for string and so on.

The format is by design engineered to be fast-to-read as all data structures are prefixed with their size so there is no scanning for null-terminated sequences.

For example, reading a string that might be demarcated like this (the []-chars are just for illustration purposes, they are not written in the format)

```
[S][512][this is a really long 512-byte UTF-8 string....]
```

You would see the 'S', switch on it to processing a string, see the 4-byte integer that follows it of "512" and know that you can just grab in one chunk the next 512 bytes and decode them back to a string.

Similarly numeric values are written out without a length value to be more compact because their type (byte, int32, int64, double) all define their length of bytes (1, 4, 8 and 8 respectively. There is also support for arbitrarily long numbers that is extremely portable, even on platforms that don't support them).

On average you should see a size reduction of roughly 30% with a well balanced JSON object (lots of mixed types). If you want to know exactly how certain structures compress or don't compress you can check the [Size Requirements](http://ubjson.org/#size) section to get an idea.

On the bright side, regardless of compression, the data will be written in a more optimized format and be faster to work with.

I checked the core [Input/OutputStream implementations](https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/universal-binary-json-java/tree/master/src/main/java/org/ubjson/io) for reading/writing the format into GitHub today. I'll check in general reflection-based object mapping later this week.

You can just look at those two classes to see how to read and write the format, I think the core logic is something like 20 lines of code. The classes are longer because of abstractions to the methods and some structuring around checking the marker bytes to make sure the data file is a valid format; things like that.

If you have really specific questions like the endianness (Big) of the spec or numeric format for doubles (IEEE 754) all of that is covered in the spec doc or just ask me.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is great! Parsing is trivial. Speed is high. Size is very good. And the representation can be understood via `tcpdump` (as opposed to protobuf's [varints](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints)). In simple hexadecimal, 300 is `0x012C`; in UBJ, `0x69012C` (since `0x69` is ascii `i`); in protobuf, `0xAC02 == 1010 1100 0000 0010`. Protobuf gets even harder (and slower) to parse if you have negative numbers. Protobuf does not compress strings or floats, so unless you have many small integers, the size is similar, but UBJ is fast and its parser is simple.

Comment: Any published benchmarks, numbers wrt speed? _Everything_ is fast to parse these days; you must compare implementations to have any idea of real speed.

Answer (score 5):

gzipping JSON data is going to get you good compression ratios with very little effort because of its universal support.  Also, if you're in a browser environment, you may end up paying a greater byte cost in the size of the dependency from a new library than you would in actual payload savings.

If your data has additional constraints (such as lots of redundant field values), you may be able to optimize by looking at a different serialization protocol rather than sticking to JSON.  Example: a column-based serialization such as Avro's [upcoming columnar store](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-806) may get you better ratios (for on-disk storage).  If your payloads contain lots of constant values (such as columns that represent enums), a dictionary compression approach may be useful too.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative that should be considered these days is [CBOR (RFC 7049)](http://cbor.io/), which has an explicitly JSON-compatible model with a lot of flexibility.   It is both stable and meets your open-standard qualification, and has obviously had a lot of thought put into it.

Comment: Very nice to see a real standard.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [BJSON](http://bjson.org) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the js-inflate to make and unmake blobs.

https://github.com/augustl/js-inflate

This is perfect and I use a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at a library I wrote. It's called minijson, and it was designed for this very purpose.
It's Python:

https://github.com/Dronehub/minijson

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AVRO? Apache Avro
https://avro.apache.org/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).