# javascript: compact serialization (JSON) of integers

Tags: javascript

I would like to transfer a large array of 2 short integers (0-65535) via JSON, in the most compact way possible. Theoretically, the most compact would be 2 bytes for each integer in binary format, but is that possible with JSON? Encoding them in hexadecimal, for example `ff4a` will require 4 bytes, which is double the size and can be important for large datasets. Is there a more compact/efficient way?

The said dataset will be received and parsed by javascript.

example in hexadecimal:

`"array": "f1f0a1a2e3e4"` this string will be split into
"f1f0", "a1a2", "e3e4" and each parsed into a number.
but this is 12 bytes, for 3 short integers (6 bytes)

Comment: Can you show an excerpt from that array?

Comment: Well if you use the actual byte values, that will result in `\uXXXX` in the JSON for every byte value that does not match to an ASCII character, so that would be even longer. I think, if you are going for “compact” here, then you probably don’t want JSON in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compact binary representation of json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893161/compact-binary-representation-of-json)

Comment: Concatenate bits —> Base64 —> GZip?